# Next.js Hot Reload doesn't work inside docker project with WSL2 Windows

Tags: docker, next.js, containers, wsl-2, hot-reload

I am running a docker-based next.js project. All development is done inside of the a dev container (docker). It uses the WSL2 and dockerDesktop. My system is windows 11. The problem is the hot reload of next.js doesn't work. When I made changes on saving, the next.js app didn't detect changes. This results in constantly refreshing the server with (npm run dev) so I can view my changes.

I put the project on the desktop on my Windows 11. In the WSL2, I can find the project folder is in
*/mnt/c/Users/liang/OneDrive/Desktop/open_source/frontend*

Below is my envioment

[image]

[image]

[image]

Package.json

```json
    {
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev -p 4000",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "test": "jest",
    "test.watch": "jest --watch",
    "db.clear": "mongosh \"mongodb://localhost:27017/ramses?readPreference=primary&ssl=false\" --eval 'db.dropDatabase(\"ramses\")'",
    "db.init": "mongosh \"mongodb://localhost:27017/ramses?readPreference=primary&ssl=false\" .submodules/ecommerce/db/nosql/*"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "7.16.0",
    "@babel/core": "7.16.5",
    "@elastic/elasticsearch": "^8.2.1",
    "@elastic/react-search-ui": "^1.13.0",
    "@elastic/react-search-ui-views": "^1.13.0",
    "@elastic/search-ui": "^1.12.1",
    "@elastic/search-ui-app-search-connector": "^1.13.0",
    "@elastic/search-ui-elasticsearch-connector": "^1.14.0",
    "@headlessui/react": "^1.6.4",
    "@heroicons/react": "^1.0.6",
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^2.8.8",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
    "@sendgrid/mail": "^7.7.0",
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.2",
    "autoprefixer": "latest",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.3",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "bl": "^5.0.0",
    "browserify-fs": "^1.0.0",
    "enhanced-resolve": "^5.8.3",
    "eslint": "^8.6.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "^12.0.7",
    "follow-redirects": "^1.14.8",
    "form-data": "^4.0.0",
    "mailgun": "^0.5.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.3",
    "mongodb": "^4.7.0",
    "mongoose": "^6.3.8",
    "multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1",
    "nanoid": "^3.2.0",
    "next": "^12.1.6",
    "next-auth": "^4.5.0",
    "next-auth-client": "^1.5.0",
    "next-connect": "^0.12.2",
    "next-i18next": "^11.0.0",
    "node-fetch": "^3.2.6",
    "nodemailer": "^6.7.2",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.16",
    "object-keys": "^1.1.1",
    "path-browserify": "^1.0.1",
    "postcss": "^8.4.12",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.25.0",
    "react-responsive-carousel": "^3.2.22",
    "react-table": "^7.7.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2",
    "react-toastify": "^8.2.0",
    "semver": "^7.3.5",
    "sharp": "^0.30.5",
    "stripe": "^9.5.0",
    "tailwind-styled-components": "^2.1.7",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.1.3",
    "typescript": "^4.7.3",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "webpack": "^5.73.0",
    "yup": "^0.32.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "12.1.2",
    "babel-jest": "27.3.1",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "3.0.0",
    "jest": "27.3.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: This has been an open WSL2 issue for 2½ years https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4739. Some hot reload systems support polling instead of notifications which seems to get around it. Weird flaws like this made me drop WSL2 and go back to a plain Linux VM.

Comment: How about downgrading to WSL1?

Comment: I'm pretty happy with the VM. It doesn't have the integrations that WSL2 has, but it works as I expect it to work :)